# When I plug in earphones or HDMI, I have to manually change the speaker settings

Tags: sound, hdmi, headphones, default

Whenever I plug in my earphones or HDMI cord, the speaker settings don't automatically change to output from them. I have to go into the sound settings and manually choose them and then do a speaker test before the will work. I just want it to automatically switch to them if I plug them in. I am using 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I've got something you can try. 
If you search for Multimedia Systems Select on the Dash. Open it and go to the Audio tab, where you can select the default audio Input and Output devices.

This should be installed by default. If it isn't, you can always run `sudo apt-get install gnome-media`. If it is not shown in the Dash, run:

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/gstreamer-properties.desktop`. In the resulting text file, go to the line starts with `NoDisplay=`. Change the `NoDisplay=true` to `NoDisplay=false` I had the same problem. Sometimes when I try to change the volume I still have to switch, but my computer always has issues that make zero sense, so I'd still give it a shot. Good luck!